# Preview an Image withing input Frame before uploading

Tags: javascript, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, image-preloader

I saw one preview image and delete before uploading design online and I've been trying to do it but nothing really works. I want to be able to preview an image within the input element frame. Something like this:

[image]

Sorry my english is not that good. I tried doing it this way

HTML CODE

```
<form>
<div class="row row-images">
  <label for="image">Images*</label>                   
  <div class="column image_container">
        <div class="post-image-collection">
        <label id="list">

        </label>
      <label class="post-image post-image-placeholder mrm mts empty">
        <input type="file" id="Photofile" name="images[]" required="required" multiple />
  <span class="icon-camera"><img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_134042.png"></span>
  <p class="uppercase">Photo</p>

</label>
</div>                        
      </div>
     </form>
```

CSS CODE

```
form .post-image-collection {
    margin: -20px 0px 0px -20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    form .post-image {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 152px;
    width: 170px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .mrm {
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .mts {
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
    form .post-image img {
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    form .post-image .icon-camera {
    display: none;
    }
    form .post-image input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    form .post-image.empty {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

    form .post-image.empty .icon-camera {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: inherit;
    margin: -15px 0px 0px -15px;
    }
    form .post-image.empty .icon-camera img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    }
    form .post-image.empty input {
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    form .post-image p, .file_container-orange p {
    margin: 10px 0;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "OpenSansSemiBold",sans-serif;
    }
    .uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    #list{
    float: left;
    }
    .thumb {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .remove_img_preview {
    position: relative;
    top: -46px;
    right: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 3px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    .remove_img_preview:before {
    content: "×";
    }
```

Javascript Code

```
var count=0;
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var $fileUpload = $("input#Photofile[type='file']");
    count=count+parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);

    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 4 || count>3) {
        alert("You can only upload a maximum of 3 photos");
        count=count-parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb mrm mts" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><span class="remove_img_preview"></span>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

$('#Photofile').change(function(evt){
    handleFileSelect(evt);
});  

$('#list').on('click', '.remove_img_preview',function () {
    $(this).parent('span').remove();

    //this is not working...
    var i = array.indexOf($(this));
    if(i != -1) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
    // tried this too:
    //$(this).parent('span').splice( 1, 1 );

    count--;
});
```

Please any help?

Comment: Damn, I thought someone could have an idea on how to do it. Guess I will forget about this design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. Find it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/zjKMcigaZ3t6kLZv9aOc?p=preview. Also you don't need to check if the uploaded files is an image using javascript. You can prevent user from uploading other files using the `accept` attribute. Like this:

```
accept="image/*"
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I already did this before and Thank you for pointing out my mistake. But what I meant is that, I want the image to preview inside the box with a delete button like on the picture above instead of previewing on the side. Is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: Those image boxes are separete boxes with different inputs. The first one is the one after you have uploaded an image and the remaining ones are the ones before you upload an image

Comment: So from the start you want to have 3 boxes(photo 1, photo 2, photo 3). On uploading an image, you want to preview it in that corresponding box with a close button. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want. Sorry my english not that good. That's what I've been trying to do all day but couldn't do it unfortunately. :(

Comment: I have modified the plunker as per your requirements. Please check.

Comment: Sorry. Dont know php.

Comment: Hey man are there? I have finally succeeded to solve my upload of multiple images  using PHP. But the issue now is that the JavaScript seems to be disturbing. For example, Whenever I click on the upload image button and select for example 3 images at once, It uploads and adds all the images to my database without a giving an error . But When I choose the images one by one, It just uploads and adds only one image to my database. Can you quickly have a look at the JS?

I tried to test it using echo count($_files) and exit function and it's clearly not the php part having a problem.

Comment: I'm using now this https://plnkr.co/edit/ayxRbyYOt3QNJAbkXiMz?p=preview

Comment: this plunker doesnt seem to work. its not doing anything.

Comment: I just noticed. On my machine in the main code it works fine. And I copy exactly the script for the image preview

Comment: I remember you fixed it, before I decided to change it. You told me something like that "I have fixed your code. Also you don't need to check if the uploaded files is an image using javascript. You can prevent user from uploading other files using the accept attribute. Like this:

accept="image/*". Can you please quickly check it like you did the first time?

Comment: Yeah I did. Its the answer that I posted above.

Comment: yeah I saw that answer and It was what I originally intended to do. But before that answer you corrected my code using the first code I sent to you https://plnkr.co/edit/ayxRbyYOt3QNJAbkXiMz?p=preview and told me some errors.